# Buttons break line after '<' char on Android

Tags: android, html, css

I'm having a weird bug. In every `<button>` and `<a>` element I have on my page where ever there is a '<' it breaks line.
If I add to the css 'white-space: nowrap;' it will fix it, giving it 'display:inline;' fixes it as well.

what can be the reason for this? and is there any legit fix?

[image]

**EDIT:**

for some reason the arrows that point to the right are working fine!

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

empty here it is in jsfiddle, only direction rtl is set. https://jsfiddle.net/tcycujeL/8/
check it in chrome over an android device

```
#wrapper{
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Comment: And the `<` is in the HTML? Unescaped?

Comment: edit: i did, works with left side one but when i use the right side one it still breaks.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: here you go: https://imgur.com/a/2Hcok

Comment: can't share the code.. sorry. but i will try to recreate it in jsfiddle and i will edit with a link.

btw, if i have the direction set to ltr it doesn't break line.

Comment: @MrLister here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tcycujeL/8/.

as you can see there is no css.

Comment: Oh, only in Chrome on an Android phone, yes, that wasn't clear before. Now I can reproduce the problem. I also updated the fiddle, so that it has two buttons with the arrows pointing both ways and the problem is visible. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/tcycujeL/10/ It looks like a bug, so I'm not sure there is a solution. You already found workarounds though.

Comment: @MrLister \shrug .. reported to google, hope they fix this. thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "every element is a new line". It's not by every element. But the most has `display: block`. A block element has the max width of the page except when using the `width` property. So `display: inline` sets the display likes a long text (like span). When you want to size it, you can  use `display: inline-block` (like images in a text).

Comment: `display: table-cell` then

Comment: Apparently it's a bug. I reported it to the chromium team and they said they are on it.